# Populate a HTML ordered list from a Spring MVC List Attribute

Tags: javascript, list, jsp, spring-mvc, html-lists

In my Spring Controller, I have an array of directions. I want to use that array, or make it into a list, and then populate an ordered list on my JSP page.

For example, I am already populating a dropdown on my JSP page with a list attribute from my controller.

Code...

Controller

```
ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT make FROM data ORDER BY make");
List<LabelValueModel> dropDownItems = new ArrayList<LabelValueModel>();
while (result.next()) {
       String make = result.getString(1);
       LabelValueModel item = new LabelValueModel(make, make);  
       dropDownItems.add(item);
}
model.addAttribute("dropDownItems", dropDownItems);
```

JSP

```
<form:select path="dropDownItems" id="carMake" onchange="selectedMake(this.value)"><br />
    <form:option label="Please select a make" value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"/>
    <form:options items="${dropDownItems}" itemLabel="label" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```

What I want to do, or something similar, is this. Obviously this code is not correct...

Controller (lets keep it the same just for the example)

```
ResultSet result = select.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT make FROM data ORDER BY make");
List<LabelValueModel> dropDownItems = new ArrayList<LabelValueModel>();
while (result.next()) {
       String make = result.getString(1);
       LabelValueModel item = new LabelValueModel(make, make);  
       dropDownItems.add(item);
}
model.addAttribute("dropDownItems", dropDownItems);
```

But for the JSP, I'd like to do something like this...

```
<ol>
  <li items="${dropDownItems}" itemValue="value"></li>
</ol>
```

Hopefully someone knows what I am looking to do any can help me out! Thanks!

Answer...

I used an array rather than a list in the situation in the controller

Controller...

```
String[] dropDownItems = new String[3];
dropDownItems[0] = "foo1";
dropDownItems[1] = "foo2";
dropDownItems[2] = "foo3";
model.addAttribute("dropDownItems", dropDownItems);
```

JSP...

```
<c:forEach items="${dropDownItems}" var="item">
    <li>${item}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

Result...

- foo1
- foo2
- foo3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in Spring JSTL tags to create a ordered or unordered list of items with a single tag, at least not one that I know of.  You will need to use a loop, like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${dropDownItems}" var="item">
   <li>${item.value}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

Your alternative is to write your own tag to do this.